# How does this C function work

Tags: c

```
#define BASE32_ONIONLEN 16
#define BASE32_ALPHABET "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz234567"

void base32_onion(char *dst, unsigned char *src) { // base32-encode hash
    uint8_t byte = 0, // dst location
    offset = 0; // bit offset
    for(; byte < BASE32_ONIONLEN; offset += 5) {
        if(offset > 7) {
            offset -= 8;
            src++;
        }
        dst[byte++] = BASE32_ALPHABET[(htobe16(*(uint16_t*)src) >> (11-offset))
                                       & (uint16_t)0x001F];
    }
    dst[byte] = '\0';
}
```

I'm having trouble understanding the part that starts with `dst[byte++]` . I am a python programmer, I'm not exactly sure how all the type conversion works. `src` points to a byte right? and `(uint16_t*)` converts that to a pointer to a 2 byte value? so does that make the byte at `src` the start of a two byte value, or the end? and what is with the `>> (11-offset)` thing?

Comment: BASE32_ALPHABET is 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz234567'
BASE32_ONION is 16

Comment: Please include that information in the question, not in a comment -- preferably by showing the declarations of `BASE32_ALPHABET` and `BASE32_ONION`.

Comment: It is basically creating a new string `dst` from `BASE32_ALPHABET` in a jumbled fashion based on its logic. Take your first case `offset=0` `byte=0` and walk though the logic. (you will need the return from `htobe16`), but it will pick letters/numbers from `BASE32_ALPHABET` on each pass.

Comment: You should really be asking a friend or a mentor about this. This is not a good fit for SO.

Comment: `*(uint16_t*)src` is UB -- it accesses an unaligned pointer as a short. On some platforms this will simply crash.

Comment: "How does this C function work" - it does not (as mentioned by @nneonneo). And `>>` is a binary right shift operator (google it if you don't know what it means).

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Except, it Does work, because this is copy pasted from the Shallot source that is used for making custom hidden service domains. https://github.com/katmagic/Shallot/blob/master/src/print.c

Comment: @Broseph "it does work because it is copy pasted from X place" - flawed reasoning (in particular, it's confusing *observed behavior* with *defined behavior*). It has undefined behavior no matter what. If it "works" (== appears to be working), that's either bad luck, non-standard (and undocumented, insofar you didn't mention any platform) behavior or black magic or all of these.

Answer (score 0):

```
uint16_t t1, t2, t3;
uint8_t t4, t5, t6;

t1 = *(uint16_t*)src;       // Whatever src is pointing to, treat the next
                            // 16 bits as an unsigned number
                            // Safer would be memcpy(&t1, src, sizeof(t1));
t2 = htobe(t1);             // Guessing this changes the value to have big-endian
                            // byte order
t3 = t2 >> (11-offset);     // Shift t2 to the right by (11-offset) bits
t4 = t3 & (uint16_t)0x001F; // t4 contains the lower 5 bits of t3
t5 = BASE32_ALPHABET[t4];   // t5 gets the t4-th byte of the base32 alphabet
t6 = byte++;                // t6 gets the value of byte, byte's value is then
                            // incremented, so t6 + 1 == byte
dest[t6] = t5;              // t5 is assigned to dest[t6]
```

Bit shifting to the right a value by n bits is equivalent to dividing the value by 2<sup>n</sup>.

Comment: I know what bit shifting does, I'm just not sure why the code does `(11-offset)` and then looks at only the first 5 bits of `t2 >> (11-offset)`. This  does help me though, thanks.

Comment: This is just the nature of the base32 onion hash algorithm. I could spend the time to reverse engineer it, but you aren't paying my salary. Hopefully this will be enough to motivate you to figure out the rest.